# External CD Drive That Doubles For Sata Access

Tags: hard-disk

So I use this USB to Sata + Power converter to hook up drives to my laptop like so.

[image]

It works for hard drives but not cd drives.
I would like to be able to hot swap the same drive between a desktop and laptop.

Is there one for CD drives so it can be hot swapped between sata and usb?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this isn't possible.  So I tested the device I bought below and it doesn't work with cd drives.  I am not sure why.

This appears to work but only works on the laptop cd drives.  Which means the power would be a problem on a desktop computer.

USB 2.0 to 7+6 13Pin Slimline SATA Laptop CD/DVD Rom Optical Drive Adapter Cable Black/White

[https://www.amazon.com/13Pin-Slimline-Laptop-Optical-Adapter/dp/B00C574Q5G/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1485286747&sr=8-2&keywords=external+cd+drive+with+sata](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C574Q5G)